# ¿Que ruta en angular no me redirige a ningún lugar?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Buenas tardes tengo una gran duda resulta que tengo un menú por categorías dichas categorías no deberían redireccionar a ningun lado simplemente deberían servir para clickear para ahi si poder ver las paginas disponibles pero en cambio me esta redireccionando a la ruta que tengo por defecto cuando no se encuentra una url que puedo hacer para que simplemente no me redireccione a ningún lado cabe aclarar que el router link se lleva con un servicio que estoy consumiendo, lo que me llega del servicio para estos contenedores de grupos es "#", si es necesario agregar un poco de código me dicen y lo haré de inmediato muchas gracias de Antemano.

Anexo mi routing

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { LayoutComponent } from './pages/layout/layout.component';
import { AuthGuard } from './services/auth.guard';
import { ActividadesComponent } from './pages/actividades/actividades.component';
import { EstablecimientosComponent } from './pages/establecimientos/establecimientos.component';
import { RelacionGastosComponent } from './pages/relacion-gastos/relacion-gastos.component';
import { CategoriasComponent } from './pages/categorias/categorias.component';
import { PerfilesViaticosComponent } from './pages/perfiles-viaticos/perfiles-viaticos.component';
import { TrayectosComponent } from './pages/trayectos/trayectos.component';
import { GestionViaticosComponent } from './pages/gestion-viaticos/gestion-viaticos.component';
import { TransferGroupComponent } from './pages/transfer-group/transfer-group.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: LayoutComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'Actividades',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'Actividades',
                component: ActividadesComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'Establecimientos',
                component: EstablecimientosComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'RelacionGastos',
                component: RelacionGastosComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'Categorias',
                component: CategoriasComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'Profiles',
                component: PerfilesViaticosComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'Transfers',
                component: TrayectosComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'ActivityReport',
                component: GestionViaticosComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'ActivityReport/:IdActivity',
                component: GestionViaticosComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'budget',
                loadChildren: './budget/budget.module#BudgetModule',
            },
            {
                path: 'reports',
                loadChildren: './reports/reports.module#ReportsModule',
            },
            {
                path: 'backend',
                loadChildren: './backend/backend.module#BackendModule',
            },
            {
                path: 'transfersgroup',
                component: TransferGroupComponent,
            }
        ]
     },
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'Tokenlogin/:token/:Id/:IdEnt',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'LoginAprob/:token/:Id/:IdEnt/:ap/:IdGroup',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: ''
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: Hola Sbenitez73. Puedes mostrar tu archivo de rutas, y los routerlinks, así poder guiarte un poco más.

Comment: Hola, Puedes Ayudarme?

Comment: SI pero muestra el archivo rutas, y los links

Comment: Disculpa, ahí está

Answer (score 0):

```
const routes: Routes = [

    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login'},//lo llevamos a una ruta no protegida
    { path:'login', component:LoginComponent},

        {path: 'dashboard',
        component: LayoutComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'Actividades',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'Actividades',
                component: ActividadesComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'Establecimientos',
                component: EstablecimientosComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'RelacionGastos',
                component: RelacionGastosComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'Categorias',
                component: CategoriasComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'Profiles',
                component: PerfilesViaticosComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'Transfers',
                component: TrayectosComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'ActivityReport',
                component: GestionViaticosComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'ActivityReport/:IdActivity',
                component: GestionViaticosComponent,
            },
            {
                path: 'budget',
                loadChildren: './budget/budget.module#BudgetModule',
            },
            {
                path: 'reports',
                loadChildren: './reports/reports.module#ReportsModule',
            },
            {
                path: 'backend',
                loadChildren: './backend/backend.module#BackendModule',
            },
            {
                path: 'transfersgroup',
                component: TransferGroupComponent,
            }
        ]
     },

    {
        path: 'Tokenlogin/:token/:Id/:IdEnt',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'LoginAprob/:token/:Id/:IdEnt/:ap/:IdGroup',
        component: LoginComponent
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: ''//esta ruta ahora debería llevarte a login
    }
];
```

Espero que te sirva, de paso si escribes la ruta manualmente te funcionaba/ o ahora te funciona.
Un saludo.

Comment: Solo funciona si escribo las rutas manualmente así debería ser?

Comment: Porfa puedes poner como llamas a las rutas, routerlinks o router.navigate

Comment: Hola Sbenitez73. Has podido solucionar, las rutas?